# bash script for cron task minutely

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, cron

I have a Paas cron service that only run on minutely, hourly, daily, weekly. I want my script to run o every 15 minutes at 8am, 9am, 10am, 11am, 4pm and 5pm. how do I do that. Here is my not working bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
MINUTES=`date +%M`
HOUR=`date +%H`
for j in "08" "09" "10" "11" "13" "16" "17";do
    if [ "$HOUR" == "$j" ];then
    for i in "00" "15" "30" "45";do
        if [ "$MINUTES" == "$i" ];then
            (
            /usr/bin/notify-send "Script is running at "
            )
        fi
    done
    fi
done
```

Comment: Can you just not use `cron`? Why do you need to use `bash` to schedule the script?

Comment: Try with a script just doing notify-send (minutely), does it work when run from the cron service? (String comparison should be `=`, not `==`, and `date +'%H %M'|read HOUR MINUTES` would get rid of a potential problem with time wrapping between two `date` invocations).

Comment: @AntonKovalenko like this? http://pastie.org/6040989 . have tested it but nothing happens.

Comment: Did you test **just doing `notify-send` alone** ? If nothing happens as well, then you have a problem with `notify-send` and not with loops and ifs.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't just use the features of crontab?

Add this line to the crontab

```
*/15 8,9,10,11,16,17 * * * /path/bin/yourscript.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd be looking at something like (run by `cron` every minute):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

# Exit if hour not valid.

hh=$(date +%H) ; hhn=${hh##0}

if [[ $hhn -lt 8  ]] ; then exit ; fi
if [[ $hhn -gt 17 ]] ; then exit ; fi
if [[ $hhn -eq 12 ]] ; then exit ; fi
if [[ $hhn -eq 14 ]] ; then exit ; fi
if [[ $hhn -eq 15 ]] ; then exit ; fi

# Exit if not multiple of 15 minutes.

mm=$(date +%M) ; mmn=${mm##0} ; ((mm15 = mmn % 15))
if [[ $mm15 -ne 0 ]] ; then exit ; fi

# Otherwise do something.

echo Doing something at $hh:$mm
```

This has the advantage of not doing a lot of loops to check whether or not you should run.

The `${hh##0}` construct simply removes any leading zero from the hour so `08` and `09` can be used in arithmetic comparisons without being treated as invalid octal (ditto for the minute).

All of the `if` statements simply exit prematurely from the script if the hour and/or minute should prevent the run. The minute one is simpler since it's a modulo-15 calculation.

Comment: http://pastie.org/6041109 using this, but only echo the last part, not within the 15 minute mark.

Comment: @Shafiq, your pastie code is incorrect, you have changed the final exit to an echo, meaning it will run every minute during those hours. That does not match your intent based on your code.

Comment: i have remove the echo, and it still not doing nothing.

Comment: @ShafiqMustapa, I'm assuming when you removed the `echo`, you replaced with code that you actually wanted to run at the given times. Otherwise, you're correct, it _will_ do nothing. For example, if you wanted to send mail, you could insert a line using `mailx` to send it. As it stands, I gave you the framework to do something at a given time - you have to add what you actually want done.